# Updating messages from a list of messages

Tags: c#

I've not posted binding specific messages to the gridview part. This shows updating that particular message or message from a list of messages databound with an XML file. My main concern is omitting redundant code in the `else` part. Any suggestions?

```
protected void grdMessage_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    DataRow xRow;
    DataSet mdsRedirect = new DataSet();
    mdsRedirect.ReadXml(st);

    if (Request["MessageID"] != null && Convert.ToInt16(Request["MessageID"]) != 0)
    {   
        //Find specific item from XML and set updated value
        mdsRedirect.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "MessageID=" + Convert.ToInt16(Request["MessageID"]);
        if (mdsRedirect.Tables[0].DefaultView.Count > 0)
        {
            mdsRedirect.Tables[0].DefaultView[0]["MessageText"] = ((TextBox)(grdMessage.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtupdMessage"))).Text;
            mdsRedirect.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        }
        else {
            xRow = mdsRedirect.Tables[0].Rows[e.RowIndex];
            xRow["MessageText"] = ((TextBox)(grdMessage.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtupdMessage"))).Text;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        xRow = mdsRedirect.Tables[0].Rows[e.RowIndex];
        xRow["MessageText"] = ((TextBox)(grdMessage.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtupdMessage"))).Text;
    }

    grdMessage.EditIndex = -1;
    mdsRedirect.WriteXml(st);
    mdsRedirect.Dispose();
    getxml();//read XML file and bind it
}
```

Comment: Telling us what the code does is a code start.

Comment: I've not posted binding specific message to gridview part. This shows updating that particular message or message from list of messages databound with XML file. My main concern was to omit redundant code in else part. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can simplify `DataSet mdsRedirect = new DataSet();` through `mdsRedirect.Dispose();` by wrapping the creating within a `using` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's "optimized", but here's something of a simplification:

```
    protected void grdMessage_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string messageIdString = Request["MessageID"];
        int messageId = messageIdString == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt16(messageIdString);

        using (DataSet mdsRedirect = new DataSet())
        {
            DataTable table = mdsRedirect.Tables[0];
            string updateMessageText = ((TextBox)grdMessage.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtupdMessage")).Text;

            mdsRedirect.ReadXml(st);
            table.DefaultView.RowFilter = messageId == 0 ? table.DefaultView.RowFilter : "MessageID=" + messageId;
            if ((messageId != 0) && (table.DefaultView.Count > 0))
            {
                // Find specific item from XML and set updated value
                table.DefaultView[0]["MessageText"] = updateMessageText;
                table.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                table.Rows[e.RowIndex]["MessageText"] = updateMessageText;
            }

            grdMessage.EditIndex = -1;
            mdsRedirect.WriteXml(st);
        }

        getxml(); // read XML file and bind it
    }
```

Comment: This is much better and thanks for reminding me about **Using**, but is there any way we can omit UpdateRowMessageText to be appear twice and make it still work?

Comment: It possibly can with some convoluted looking `if` statements. Let me try that out and see what you think.

Comment: See how that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a C# guru, so just some general advice:

This line is really-really long, hard to read and there are too many dots in it:

```
mdsRedirect.Tables[0].DefaultView[0]["MessageText"] = ((TextBox)(grdMessage.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtupdMessage"))).Text;
```

The code use `mdsRedirect.Tables[0]` a lot of times, create a local variable for that at the beginning of the method:

```
MyTable table = mdsRedirect.Tables[0];
...
table.DefaultView[0]["MessageText"] = ((TextBox)(grdMessage.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtupdMessage"))).Text;
```

I would also extract the following method:

```
private String getTextFromRow(int rowIndex) {
    Row row = grdMessage.Rows[rowIndex];
    Control control = row.FindControl("txtupdMessage");
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox) control;
    return textBox.Text;
}
```

Then the code:

```
MyTable table = mdsRedirect.Tables[0];
...
table.DefaultView[0]["MessageText"] = getTextFromRow(e.RowIndex);
```